# Replacing option in select field (not adding)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a select field as follows:

```
<select id="field">
```

I add options based on values found in another div (OtherDiv) on my page like this:

```
window.onload = function onload()
    {
        var OtherDiv = document.getElementById('OtherDiv').innerHTML;
        var result = OtherDiv.match(/SomeRegex/gi);
        var select = document.getElementById("field");
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = i+1;
                option.innerHTML = result[i];
                select.add(option);
            }
    }
```

However, I would like to set up some alternative value for the field to show, if there are no matches to the regex. How would I best achieve that?

Comment: you create the one more option property which value is not selected and let me define this
<option value="">not selected</option>
and put in the top of options when the page is loaded and the result has no value it will automatic selected

Comment: But I don't wan't the "default" option to display at all, in the list of possible options to select from, if there are found values (i.e. regex matches).

Answer (score 1):

Use if condition

```
window.onload = function onload()
{
    var OtherDiv = document.getElementById('OtherDiv').innerHTML;
    var result = OtherDiv.match(/SomeRegex/gi);
    var select = document.getElementById("field");
    if(result.length){
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
            {
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.value = i+1;
                option.innerHTML = result[i];
               select.add(option);
            }
      }else{
           //add alternative options here
           var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.innerHTML = "No records found"; //whatever text you want to show 
               select.add(option);
      }
}
```

Comment: When I plug this into my page, it doesn't work on the "else."  When I go to a page without the condition, it simply does not put any values in the select box.  Any ideas why this might be breaking?

Comment: don't call on window.onload instead add your script at before <body> close. and call the function or use IIFE